# How to instert equation to google sheets using python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, formula, equation

When I'm trying this, in my google sheet, the cell is filled by: `'=max(9,6)` as a string. How can I make my equation usable?

here I added a google sheet and colab link to try it yourself

code example to try in colab:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

# creats a google sheet in your drive
sh = gc.create('formula_test')
#Note: using this code, you must remove the file from your drive each time 
#or use a different name

#creats a sheet 
wsh=sh.add_worksheet("test",rows=10,cols=10)

#this must a list of lists representing rows and cols
wsh.update([["5/6/22","=1+1","=max(9,6)"]])
```

Colab link:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18GXmroZnHioCS5Hui9TOeQjcAYjHfhck?usp=sharing

google sheets:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzxvOM4XTpyvh9D1ZezW_ARMZ5eLRn01K-FQrypnxlo/edit#gid=1765704977

a primitive solution for Date is to change the format to date and it will be fixed. not a nice way but at least can be used for the long column

but for formulas (equations), the only way is to delete the ' manually one by one, Replace doesn't work on it

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'll try on my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [raw option](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=formula#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update) as `False` to treat the input as a formula

```py
wsh.update([["5/6/22","=1+1","=max(9,6)"]], raw=False)
```